# Error when setup Samsung SmartUX SDK Simulator

Tags: android

When I installed Samsung SmartUX SDK Simulator, then the following error appears:
[image]

I have really find help on stackoverflow but have not any article about this problem.
Finally I also resolved this problem.
And now I want to share that experience with friends.

In my case, It's missing environment variable JAVA_HOME.
---> You need additional JAVA_HOME variable.

Hope help anyone needed.

Comment: Welcome @tuanpv - its best to put the text of your error in your body of your email. It will be easier for others to search and find this problem by the error message - this is good for you as they will upvote your answer. Please take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. NOTE You can also ask and answer your own question.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you micstr.